# Concatenating columns while pivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server

My code is as below

```
SELECT  
    Customerid, CustomerName, [ftga.ihs.com] as ftga, [Email Delivery] as Email 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         Customerid, CustomerName, AliasName, 
         Deliverylocation,FTPUsername,FTPPassword
     FROM
         [dbo].[tblCustomerDeliveryServerMapping] t1
     INNER JOIN
         tblDeliveryServerDetails t2 ON t1.Deliveryserverid = t2.id
     INNER JOIN
         tblcustomerinfo t3 ON t1.customerid = t3.id) AS P
PIVOT 
    (MAX(Deliverylocation + FTPUsername + FTPPassword) 
     FOR AliasName in ([ftga.ihs.com],[Email Delivery])
    ) AS  PVT
```

I want to concatenate FTPUsername and FTPPassword to Deliverylocation in the final result .

Above code is not working. If I remove +FTPUsername +FTPPassword, then the code works.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you do the concatenation in your subquery so that the column can be used  in `PIVOT`

```
SELECT  Customerid ,
        CustomerName ,
        [ftga.ihs.com] AS ftga ,
        [Email Delivery] AS Email
FROM    ( SELECT    Customerid ,
                    CustomerName ,
                    AliasName ,
                    Deliverylocation ,
                    FTPUsername ,
                    FTPPassword ,
                    ConcatenatedValue = Deliverylocation + FTPUsername
                    + FTPPassword
          FROM      [dbo].[tblCustomerDeliveryServerMapping] t1
                    INNER JOIN tblDeliveryServerDetails t2 ON t1.Deliveryserverid = t2.id
                    INNER JOIN tblcustomerinfo t3 ON t1.customerid = t3.id
        ) AS P PIVOT 
    ( MAX(ConcatenatedValue) FOR AliasName IN ( [ftga.ihs.com],
                                                [Email Delivery] ) ) AS PVT;
```